# Illegal string offset 'Latitude' in laravel json

Tags: php, json, laravel

My code, the `request` value should come from another server, so we just encoded & saved it in database.

```
$data->data_received = json_encode($request->all());
$data->save();

$serverData = json_decode($data->data_received);
dd($serverData->data_received['Latitude']);
```

error

```
ErrorException: Illegal string offset 'Latitude' in file tracking/app/Http/Controllers/ApiController.php on line 18
```

`$serverdata->data_received` values

```
"[
  {
    "Latitude":"23.740630",
    "Longitude":"92.796050",
    "Speed":0
  },
  {
    "Latitude":"23.736350",
    "Longitude":"92.717600",
    "Speed":0
  }
]"
```

How to get the `Latitude` value from above data, when I try `$serverData->data_received['Latitude']` I got the error I included.

If I do `$serverData = json_decode($data->data_received, true); dd($serverData['data_received']);` the values I received are same

Comment: with `$serverData->data_received['Latitude'][0]` ?

Comment: Your `$serverData` does not contain `data_received`. You created it by decoding `$data->data_received` already.

Comment: `$serverData->data_received[0]->Latitude` or if you arrayed it all `$serverData->data_received[0]['Latitude']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The json that you have is an array of values.

> If I do $serverData = json_decode($data->data_received, true); dd($serverData['data_received']); the values I received are same

Here you are creating an associative array of the contents of the json to $serverData.

To access the elements you do:

```
$serverData = json_decode($data->data_received, true);  // return associative array
dd( $serverData[0]['Latitude'] ); // where 0 is the index of the array.
```

Hope it helps.